# Passing in %20 as part of url to Twitter web intents but it shows as ' ' blank space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, web, twitter

My valid url is website.com/my%20name when I pass this into Twitter web intents the %20 gets extracted to a blank space... but this creates a bad url.

Any ideas how I can get this url in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `website.com/my%2520name`

That is, escape the `%` as `%25` for transit. When it arrives and is decoded, you'll have the intended `%20`.

Comment: Brilliant. Works as expected.